# Does Terraria on Steam need Internet connection after download?

Tags: terraria

I am thinking about buying Terraria on Steam, but I need to know if after I have downloaded the game, will it still need an internet connection for me to play it in singleplayer only?

Answer (score 9):

No. It does not need any connection if you play only singleplayer. :)

Comment: Installation doesn't require a connection. Once Steam finishes downloading, you can cut the connection, install, then play. Usual Steam offline caveats apply.

Comment: You usually need to start the game up once while online, but then afterwards you can play offline

Comment: @Lyrion Is that just a rule of thumb for steam games? In my test, I downloaded Terraria, then turned off my laptop's wifi. From thre, I was able to install Terraria, create a new character/world and play singleplayer.

Comment: @Arkive It used to be, even single player games. Well atleast it was for the ones that you can't start from the folder themselves.

Answer (score 1):

**No** it does not need Internet connection after it has been downloaded. There is a "Single Player" and "Multiplayer" option on the menu, clicking the Single Player button will create a world that is stored on your computer and can be played completely offline. [image]

To connect to a server using the "Multiplayer" menu, you will have to be connected to the Internet. You will also need to be connected to the Internet if you want to use the Steam Cloud feature to have your characters and worlds be accessible from any computer that you are logged into Steam on.

Comment: Do note that you don't need Internet at the moment of saving to Steam Cloud, but just at some point in the future so Steam can sync the data.

Comment: Yes. If at some point you have Internet connection while the game is on, then the game will back up your characters/worlds to Steam Cloud.